# Multiple Unexpected Request: GET

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have an angular app, that on initialisation, make a number of http requests.

I have set up a test, to expect the first request, and the second,

```
describe("MyController--", function () {

    var controller, scope, $httpBackend, myFactory;

    var iResponse = {
        table: 'red',
        price: '1.99'
    };

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _myFactory_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        $httpBackend.expectGET("/app/shopping/cart/layout.html").respond({});
        $httpBackend.expectGET("/app/rest/products").respond(iResponse);

        myFactory = _myFactory_;
        spyOn(myFactory, 'getData').and.callThrough();

        controller = _$controller_('MainController', {$scope: scope});
        scope.$apply();
        $httpBackend.flush();
    }));

    it('should verify that the controller exists ', function() {
        expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    });
```

With the above, i keep seeing the error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /app/rest/products
Information:    Expected GET /app/shopping/cart/layout.html
```

Any ideas what i am missing?

Comment: Is it making two calls to the API? If so u need an expect for every individual call. If u don't want to do an expect for every ca

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would preload HTML in Karma conf so you don't have to expect HTML.

Secondly does your controller make a call to the unexpected URL? If so you should expect the request.

Comment: The controller makes the call to /products... the call to the .html file is coming from my router via templateUrl

Comment: Are u making multiple calls to products? If so u need one expect get for each call. If u don't want this then use whenget